# debian.cnf file location in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, mysql

Where can I find the `debian.cnf` file in Ubuntu 14.04? It was under "`/etc/mysql/debian.cnf`" in Ubuntu 12.04.

Is there some location changes or name changes?

What I want is to reset MySQL root password, using "debian-sys-maint" user right.

I am now trying to find the file [following this one](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/find).

Comment: There is no such thing like Debian 14.04. If you mean Debian, then the latest version is 7.5; if you mean 14.04 then it is Ubuntu, not Debian.

Comment: In Ubuntu (14.04) the file can be found with locate

    locate debian.cnf
    /etc/mysql/debian.cnf

Debian itself is OFF topic on askunbuntu. You should ask this here: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we are a site dedicated to Ubuntu and you mention 14.04 I assume you are talking about Ubuntu 14.04.

You can find file locations with locate. So ...

```
$ locate debian.cnf
/etc/mysql/debian.cnf
```

edit:

This requires you to have mysql installed (as seen by Christophers' answer)

Answer (score 0):

This might help, use the `locate` utility
`➜  ~  locate debian.cnf`
`/etc/texmf/texmf.d/00debian.cnf`

Comment: He specifically mentioned mysql ;)